# Question regarding the expected value of the max of two random variables

Tags: probability

Assume that we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that take values in $\mathbb{R}$, with $\mathbb{E}(X) < 0$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y) < 0$. Does it generally hold that $\mathbb{E}(\max\{X,Y\}) <0$ ? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Suppose, for example, that $X=-1$, a constant, and that $Y =-100$ with probability $.1$ and $Y=10$  with probability $.9$.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, under your conditions on the means  of $X$ and $Y$, $\Bbb E(\min(X,Y))<0$. The easiest way to see this is to notice that $X+Y = \min(X,Y)+\max(X,Y)$.